# Pass data between views in ExtJS

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2, sencha-cmd

I am reading data from store and populating main girdView. When any of the row is clicked, a windows appear and I want to fill the fieldset in that window with the same record which is clicked. 
Can anyone tell me how to do it?

My popup window is like:

```
{
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',

    height: 500,
    width: 1500,
    minWidth :1500,
    maxWidth :1500,
    layout: 'fit',
    controller: 'PopUpWindowController',

    initComponent: function () {

        var me = this;


        //console.log(me.myExtraParams);
        var Store = Ext.getStore('mainStore');

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
         /*   items: [{
                xtype: 'form',
                bodyPadding: 10,
                region: 'center'
            }]*/

        });    
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },      
        items: [
    {      
        xtype: 'panel',
        title : 'Projektierung',
        bodyStyle : 'padding:5px',
        width : 1880,
        autoHeight : true,
        items:
        [ 
            {
                xtype  : 'kopfdatenView', // Have to populate this view
            }
        ]
}]}
```

and in Main view I am calling it as:

{
                region: 'center',
                xtype: 'gridpanel',

```
            listeners : {
                itemdblclick: function(dv, record, item, index, e) {

                    var extra = record.data;
                    win = Ext.create('App.view.PopUpWindow');

                    console.log(win.myExtraParams);

                    win.on('show', function(win) {

                     win.setTitle(record.get('ID'));
                    });

                    win.show();
                }
            },

             columns: [
                      ****
                    ],
            store: 'mainStore', 
            height: 100,
            width: 400,

        }
```

I want to  populate fieldset in kopfdatenView. Kindly help

Comment: @xaume first of all, you should write such things in comments. Also I have added the code in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You directly pass your record to your window on creation :

```
win = Ext.create('App.view.PopUpWindow', {
    myRecord: record
});
```

And then inside the window's `initComponent` function (before the `callParent`) :

```
this.title = this.myRecord.get('ID');
```

Comment: Thanks, 
It works, though there was not get function so I had to accept data as this.myRecord.ID.
But This helped me  a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
 win = Ext.create('App.view.PopUpWindow', {
           params: record
       });
```

Then, in your PopUpWindowController you can retrieve 'params' in the render event (for example).

Comment: first of all, you should write such things in comments. Also I have added the code in my question

Comment: I am marking your answer as useful cause you gave me a right answer but you didn't tell me how to access it in the other view(which @3rgo's answer does tell and that is why I am accepting that as "accepted answer"). 
Thanks a lot.